# Set project specific values by overriding Java class or Properties file, which is better?

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

I have a library doing reporting, and each projects using it need to provide custom values.
So I have 2 ways for setting these values:

1. Use properties file
2. Provide an abstract class to provide values in the library and let projects override it.

My question is which one is preferable?

---

e.g.  2 values: *consumer* & *producer*

Option 1 - properties `application.yml`:

```yaml
consumer: con
producer: pro
```

Then read into a properties class.

Option 2 - `Java` class:

```java
Public Abstract Class MyConfig{
  // project will override method and return "con";
  protected abstract getConsumer();

  protected abstract getProducer();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguments for using `properties` file:
java way is probably better when default values can be used by most projects. But since most values here do need customisation for each project, Using config file is a clearer, easier and less-pollution-to-core-business way.

To be specific, if we use java way instead:

- need to write more lines
- need to worry about injecting the new class to spring
- people who don’t care about this library will see the new class and need to figure out what it does
- for those who do care about the library, instead of an easy to find property file, they’ll have to dig into the many java files in order to change related values

---

Arguments for using `Java`:
It's for the same reason why we are writing code in an IDE instead of a text in a text editor.
With a config file, nobody checks the semantics of the config. If the underlying library changes, there will be no compiler telling you that something is wrong.
With Java class, documentation will be in place as method comments, API will be discoverable as you just check what can be overridden if needed.
We will follow what Springboot is pushing, which is java based config. We would avoid silly errors, like incorrect syntax in the text config, which will break something, etc.